# how to show a message when no results were found

Tags: amp-html

I have an amp autocomplete that searches for items using a backend endpoint while typing.
If no results were found, I want to show a custom message to inform the user that nothing was found, and maybe provide them a hint.

This is what I currently have:

```
                                <amp-autocomplete
                                    filter="none"
                                    filter-value="name"
                                    src={`${hostName}/api/areas`}
                                    on="select:AMP.setState({ defaultState: { area: event.value }}), searchform.submit"
                                    query="name"
                                    submit-on-enter="true"
                                    highlight-user-entry="true"
                                    items="items"
                                >
                                    <input
                                        dir="rtl"
                                        autoFocus
                                        type="search"
                                        name="selectedArea"
                                        role="areasearch"
                                        tabIndex="3"
                                        className="amp-search-areas-input"
                                    />

                                    <template
                                        type="amp-mustache"
                                        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={markup(`
                                        <div data-value="{{name}}" class="search-dropdown">
                                             <div>{{ name }}</div>
                                        </div>`)}
                                    />
                                </amp-autocomplete>
```

Comment: see this: `<div class="-tk" [hidden]="search.initial == true || search.result.totalResults != 0" hidden> <h2 class="-t_">¯\_(ツ)_/¯</h2> <h3 class="ap-o-search-result-error-headline">No results found.</h3> <p class="-tq">We could not find any results matching your search query.</p></div>` at amp.dev

Comment: @JayGray That did not work sadly. Where can I find some docs about the params you used?